# Failed to execute 'getStats' on 'RTCPeerConnection' on Twilio JS 1.4.16

Tags: javascript, webrtc, twilio, twilio-api, twilio-click-to-call

I'm using Twilio on an Electron app, currently the chrome version it uses is 56. I've upgraded my twilio version from 1.3 to 1.4.16. When I start an audio call, everything goes fine, however I get an error on console that might be related to RTC statistics. That's the error:

```
Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Failed to execute 'getStats' on 'RTCPeerConnection': No function was found that matched the signature provided.
at getStatistics (twilio.js:5011)
at RTCMonitor.getSample (twilio.js:3716)
at RTCMonitor._fetchSample (twilio.js:3732)
```

I couldn't find any clue about that, searching on google.

Comment: What browser are you testing this in? Do you have voice insights enabled for your account?

Comment: I'm using Electron that uses Chrome 56.

Comment: philnash, yes I do have voice insights enable.